# While parsing text to remove <> tags are being added. How do I fix that?

Tags: html, regex, replace, innerhtml

I've got these outputs from using git `status` that have `<file>` in them that I've been manually adding to an html file.

I'm trying to replace the <> in a code tag in html so `<file>` shows up as regular text instead of being tags.

In Firefox the end tags `</file>` keep being inserted.

Any way here's the code:

```
var codeMe = function(){
    var code = document.getElementsByTagName('code'),
        text = '';
    for(var i=0; i<code.length; i++){
        text = code[i].innerHTML;
        text = text.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        text = text.replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        code[i].innerHTML = text;
    }
};
codeMe();
```

The tags are being inserted before the `codeMe()` function is even called. When I inspect the `code` with `codeMe()` commented out those `</file>` ending tags are there.

If I can't stop the browser from doing that I'll just have to remove the those extra tags after the <> are replaced. Though I'd prefer a better way if there is one.

Comment: The `</file>` tags are caused by the parse/serialization cycle. If your not going to html-encode the `<file>` strings before putting them in the DOM, the `</file>` tags are inevitable on serializing with innerHTML. But they will always be exactly the same form, so just string find & delete them.

Comment: @Alohci ok. Should be easy enough. I just thought there might be some other way. The `<file>` strings are a part of the html when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQn97/)

```
(function codeMe() {
    $('code').text($('code').html());
})();
```

This of course using my HTML:

```
<div id=one>See me</div>
<code> <file> You dont see me </file> </code>
```

Only after posting this did I actually look what you wanted and jQuery was not one of them.

Well it's here if someone else needs it I guess :\

Comment: It's ok. I like jQuery, but it doesn't fit this project. Nice to know for future reference. I'll upvote.